# what is z in reprojectImageTo3D()

Tags: python, opencv

What is this *z* in OpenCV `reprojectImageTo3D()`?

[image: 1]

How can I use Q matrix to reproject a point with `(x,y,disparity)` into space?

I've tried set that value to 1 but it didn't work.

Also: If I have a 3d point, how can I project it into pixels using Q matrix?

Comment: Did you check what kind of content is in the disparity map returned by one of the opencv functions?

Comment: According to this example, https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/110697/cv2.reprojectImageTo3D you just give the disparity map, as a single channel matrix without any z. But when you use opencv stereo matching, you might need to divide the dusparity map by 16 and convert to float. See the docs of reprojectImageTo3D

Comment: Sorry, read your question again. reprojectImageTo3D is NOT for projecting 3D points to the image, it is for bringing pixel points to 3D space. Use cv projectPoints to project from 3D to image.

Comment: best to ignore that part of the docs involving "Q". it's incomprehensible.

Comment: Yes, this part is difficult to understand. But how can I reproject a point using Q matrix or something based on binocular calibration parameter？

Comment: OK，I got it. This z value should be set to 1. I made a mistake for disparity.